Как использовать ввод, одновременно перехватывая нажатия стрелок (C++, Linux)
Я пишу CLI программу и при нажатии стрелок вверх/вниз должна прокручиваться история команд. Но есть проблема: при использовнии std::getline и std::cin невозможно перехватить их нажатие. Единственное, до чего я додумался, это реализовать цикл с функцией getchar, но получается относительно раздутый код:
constexpr int ENTER_KEY_CODE = 10;
constexpr int ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_1 = 27;
constexpr int ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_2 = 91;
constexpr int UP_ARROW_KEY_CODE = 65;
constexpr int DOWN_ARROW_KEY_CODE = 66;
constexpr int BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE = 127;

static std::string read() noexcept
{
  std::string input;
  int inputCode = 0;
  while (inputCode != ENTER_KEY_CODE)
  {
    inputCode = getchar();
    switch (inputCode)
    {
    case ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_1:
      if (getchar() == ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_2)
      {
        switch (getchar())
        {
        case UP_ARROW_KEY_CODE:
          /* ... */
          break;
        case DOWN_ARROW_KEY_CODE:
          /* ... */
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case ENTER_KEY_CODE:
      /* ... */
      break;
    case BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE:
      /* ... */
      break;
    default:
      /* ... */
      break;
    }
  }
  return std::move(input);
}

Как перехватить нажатие стрелок при вводе? Только без (n)curses.

Если вы имеете в виду, как читать stdin не дожидаясь нажатия , то нужно перевести терминал в raw noecho mode. (Читайте man termios и manpages из SEE ALSO в нем)

Я это уже делал, вопрос именно в том, как во время чтения перехватывать некоторые клавишы? Есть ли другое решение, помимо реализации такого цилка?

тут скорее дожидаться энтер и в фоне мониторить.  в таком варианте повесить O_NONBLOCK и работать по select

а так лучше прикрути готовую ncurces

@user589514, "Есть ли другое решение, помимо реализации такого цилка?" -- вообще говоря, нет. С разными вариациями (например, таблица, привязывающая распознанную эскеп-последовательность к действию, таймаут на ввод последовательности и т.п.) все примерно так и делают

Спасибо большое за ответ! Еще небольшой вопрос: нужно ли реализовывать нажатие на Backspace и Enter самому, или есть какие-нибудь функции для этого? Например, я столкнулся с такой проблемой: при вводе символа он добавляется к строке input, но он не отображается. Использовать std::cout не вариант, т.к. символы записываются в stdout, а не в stdin.

В raw mode вы все редактирование (backspace, delete и т.д) делаете сами (если оставить echo, то при вводе символов от стрелок и т.п. на экране будут лишние символы). Если хотите, чтобы вводимые символы отображались, то выводите их сами в stdout (в предположении, что stdin и stdout связаны с одним и тем же tty). Обратите внимание, что получение вами bacspace не вызовет автоматически удаление последнего echo-символа.  Его надо затереть пробелом самому, выводя "\b \b"

Кстати, если обращаетесь в комментарии к конкретному участнику и хотите чтобы он получил нотификацию о вашем комментарии, то начинайте свой комментарий с @nick (автор вопроса или ответа получает нотификацию о всех комментариях к своему тексту, а я увидел ваш новый комментарий лишь заглянув сюда)

@avp, Я так и делал) Странно, что нет небольшой библиотеки для этого, но я щас оставлю ответ. Спасибо Вам еще раз!

Насчет библиотек: все зависит от того, что именно вам надо. Есть curses для работы с меню и т.п., есть GNU readline (вместе с history) для ввода и редактирования строк (как в bash)

Да, я думал в верном направлении: без (n)curses всё делается вручную вместе с перехватом нажатий на Backspace, Enter и т.д. Вот как это примерно выглядит:
constexpr int ENTER_KEY_CODE = 10;
constexpr int ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_1 = 27;
constexpr int ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_2 = 91;
constexpr int UP_ARROW_KEY_CODE = 65;
constexpr int DOWN_ARROW_KEY_CODE = 66;
constexpr int BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE = 127;

static std::string read() noexcept
{
  std::string input;
  int inputCode = 0;
  while (inputCode != ENTER_KEY_CODE)
  {
    inputCode = getchar();
    switch (inputCode)
    {
    case ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_1:
      if (getchar() == ARROW_KEY_CODE_SEQUENCE_2)
      {
        switch (getchar())
        {
        case UP_ARROW_KEY_CODE:
          /* ... */
          break;
        case DOWN_ARROW_KEY_CODE:
          /* ... */
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case ENTER_KEY_CODE:
      std::cout << std::endl;
      break;
    case BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE:
      input = std::move(input.substr(1, input.size()));
      std::cout << "\b \b";
      break;
    default:
      input += inputCode;
      std::cout << (char)inputCode;
      break;
    }
  }
  return std::move(input);
}

Перехватывать исключения и тестировать код я пока не стану, это общая логика.
Update: Как подсказали в комментариях, можно использовать библиотеку GNU Readline, что тоже подойдет для решения данной проблемы.

Ну, если выбросить С++, то и об исключениях думать не придется (а вот о том, что в utf-8 один символ на экране может быть несколькими в input[], а также о том, что происходит, когда вводят больше символов, нежели вмещает строка терминала, подумать стоит)

Ну вопрос состоит не в этом, если что-то надо - можно реализовать.
